# Convert equal interval of vector to rows of matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vector, type-conversion, diagonal

I've imported table that contains the travel times for an origin-destination cost matrix of size nxn. As a result, travel times equal to zero when an origin and destination are the same.

For example, an OD cost matrix of 25 origins and 25 destinations (625 elements) would have zero values running down the diagonal. In a vector, the value 0 occurs at the 0th element, 26th element, 51st element, etc.

I've read the travel times in as a vector and I'd like to reshape the vector into a matrix where every element on the diagonal has the value of zero. Does anyone have any ideas on how this would be done?

Code:

```
### READ and PREPARE DATA ###
# Read OD cost matrix (use data.table for performance)
od_table <- read.table('DMatrix.txt', sep=',', header=TRUE, na.strings="NA", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

v <- t(od_table$Total_TravelTime)
n <- sqrt(length(v))

D <- matrix(v, nrow=25)
```

The resulting matrix has zero values along the first row only:
[image]

Comment: data and code please!

Comment: I think you're asking how to convert a vector into a matrix. In the 3x3 case with `vec <- c(0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 4, 2, 4, 0)`, you can do `mat <- matrix(vec, nrow=3)`. The only thing different in your case is `nrow=25`.